# How can I store System.Data.SQLite.dll in subfolder?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, reference, bin

I'm using Visual Studio to create C# application which uses SQLite database.
What I want to do is save DLL file in subfolder named 'config'. I've created config folder inside bin/debug folder and copied System.Data.SQLite.dll file into it.
Then I added Reference to my solution using bin/debug/config/Systtem.Data.SQLite.dll file.
The problem is that every time I build solution VS creates new System.Data.SQLite.dll file directly inside bin/debug and when I try to use my application (after deleting bin/debug/System.Data.SQLite.dll) it throws an exception = it cannot load dll from inside config folder...
How can I solve it?

Comment: This will probably help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110553/how-to-save-dlls-in-a-different-folder-when-compiling-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ought to use the default behavior of loading from the EXE's directory.

If you really don't want to, set `Copy Local` to false on the reference and load the DLL yourself by calling `Assembly.Load`.
Note that you'll need to load the DLL before calling any methods that use its types so that the DLL is already loaded when the runtime JITs the methods.

Comment: It might be a good idea to use this in conjunction with `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`. That way it's loaded only on demand, and the intent of what is going on is a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some more info on the topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb.aspx