# C# Express - Build class project in subfolder

Tags: c#, class-library, subdirectory, visual-c#-express-2010

I have a solution in C# Express 2010 which has multiple class libraries in it. When I build my program, the .exe and all of the .dll files are put in the same folder.

Is there any way for me to specify which subfolders I can place the .dll libraries in? 
For example, put the main .exe in the root folder and the .dll files in a subfolder called "lib".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110553/how-to-save-dlls-in-a-different-folder-when-compiling-in-visual-studio

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that one when looking for it. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your build output for each project. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165410.aspx

Comment: I tried doing this in the project for the class library however it didn't actually change anything in the output folder.