# How to make PrettyBin not copy PDB files to lib folder in order to show Exception line numbers?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, post-build-event

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27943743/1847868) I installed `PrettyBin` to my VS2013 C# project. It really is a easy one click solution if you want to copy all referenced DLLs to a lib subfolder in the bin folder.

Recently I noticed that thrown `Exceptions` do not show line numbers anymore. Searching trough Q&As here I think it is because `PrettyBin` moves the `MyApp.pdb` file to the `\lib` subfolder along with all DLLs. And now I don't know how to undo that. Uninstalling `PrettyBin` from `NuGet` does not help. Seems that its changes are permanent and I don't know where to look to configure this behaviour. My Project's post build events list is empty.

If anyone has experience with `PrettyBin`, how can I configure it to skip pdb files?

Otherwise where, should I look to make a change in the Project properties so I can get my pdb back to the bin folder?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. I had to manually change the `MyApp.csproj` file with Notepad++. The part at the very end where it says:

```xml
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <ItemGroup>
    <MoveToLibFolder Include="$(OutputPath)*.dll ; $(OutputPath)*.pdb ; $(OutputPath)*.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Move SourceFiles="@(MoveToLibFolder)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)lib" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

I just had to remove `$(OutputPath)*.pdb ;` AND remove `PrettyBin` from the NuGet Package Manager, so it doesn't change it back again. Now all DLLs and XMLs go to `\lib` subfolder, but the .pdb stays put and I again get the line number when catching Exceptions.

Comment: Actually I cannot find any pdb's for the dll's. Neither in the top level folder, nor the `\lib` subfolder.