# MSBuild: copy whole folder

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

Trying to copy a whole folder, but when I do this:

```
<Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetDir)\*.*" DestinationFolder="$(BuildOutput)\SomeDir" />
```

the copy attempts to do this: **copy c:\source\*.* c:\destination\SomeDir\*.***  and fails with `illegal characters` error

Comment: A similar question has been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119271/copy-all-files-and-folders-using-msbuild

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Specify your ItemGroup for SourceFiles explicitly.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <_CopyItems Include="$(TargetDir)\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
<Copy
    SourceFiles="@(_CopyItems)"
    DestinationFolder="$(BuildOutput)\SomeDir"
    />
```

Note that _CopyItems is an item type, so it's referenced using '@' symbol rather than '$'.

Comment: Better add `<InProject>false</InProject>` to the item group, otherwise you will see all your bin folder contents in solution explorer.
`<ItemGroup>
    <_CopyItems Include="$(TargetDir)*.*">
       <InProject>false</InProject>
       </_CopyItems>
  </ItemGroup>`

Answer (score 63):

Copying files can be done with the following code snippet which handles antivirus programs and subdirectories

```
  <ItemGroup>
        <SomeAppStuff Include="$(SolutionDir)\ProjectXXX\bins\**\*.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy 
      SourceFiles="@(SomeAppStaff)" 
      DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\%(RecursiveDir)" 
      SkipUnchangedFiles="true"
      OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" 
      Retries="3"
      RetryDelayMilliseconds="300"/>
```

Specifying `$(OutputPath)\%(RecursiveDir)` will ask Copy task to respect subfolders, so it will place subfolders of source directory to subfolders of target directories.

`SkipUnchangedFiles` will increase build speed on computers with enough memory, because Windows optimizes IO for frequently used files when there's enough RAM.

`Retries` and `RetryDelayMilliseconds` handles issues related 
a) Compressed NTFS file system, when builds fails in seldom cases b) Antivirus Software with SSD drives.

Comment: What are the ramifications of setting the `DestinationFolder` to path\%(RecursiveDir)? Will it place the directory at the intended location, or whatever is farthest down the recursion pathing,

Comment: kayleeFrye_onDeck, It will place subfolders of source dir in subfolders of destination directory, if to remove that, content of all subfolders of source directory will be placed to destination directory.

Comment: Thank you, my folders were being created but all files put into the root until I chaned to `%(RecursiveDir)`.

Comment: Curious can MS Build cope with a drive letter I have to create  a physical folder at time of msbuild but it cant be in the main web site

Answer (score 42):

If you put the folder in the root of your c# project then you can simple put this in your csproj.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="FolderToCopy\**\*.*">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

I have only tested in the 2017 version of csproj, but I assume it's backwards compatible. Could be wrong on that though

Answer (score 14):

Looking at the MSDN documentation, I believe the SourceFiles parameter requires an ITaskItem[] value. See [MSDN MSBuild Copy Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx)

The last example on the above link is to do a recursive copy from one directory to another, maintaining the folder structure.

Answer (score 9):

Succeeded to accomplish this task like this

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <ItemGroup>
    <SomeDir Include="$(SolutionDir)\SomeOtherProject\SomeDir\**\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy 
    SourceFiles="@(SomeDir)" 
    DestinationFiles="@(SomeDir->'$(OutDir)\SomeDir\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" 
    SkipUnchangedFiles="true" 
    OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" 
    Retries="3" 
    RetryDelayMilliseconds="300" />
```

Answer (score 8):

For me what worked was this:
- kept folder structure
- copied all files within the folder
- works for any folder, doesn't have to be in the project or the same project folder

```
<ItemGroup>
    <_CopyItems Include="<path relative to project>\**\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(_CopyItems)" DestinationFiles="@(_CopyItems->'$(OutDir)\<output folder>\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
</Target>
```

legend:

- `<path relative to project>`: this could be any path, using ..\ for
  going above the proj folder works
- `<output folder>`: folder you want
  the whole file structure to be dropped into, excluding the source
  folder.
- `$(OutDir)` will be bin\Debug or whatever build mode you have, if you want something
  else, change that.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 15.4+, there's a feature that makes this easier - you can set `LinkBase` or `Link` to control the destination path:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="FolderToCopy\**" LinkBase="FolderInOutput\" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
</ItemGroup>
```

source: https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/2949#issuecomment-362823310

Comment: Thanks! Simple and concise!  
[Common macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=msvc-170) like `$(ProjectDir)` are working with this approach as well.

Answer (score -2):

The best solution for me was to use the magic `XCOPY` as I had to copy all files and sub directories

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <FilesSource>$(ProjectDir)\lib</FilesSource>
    <FilesDestination Condition=" '$(SolutionName)' == 'any name a' ">$(ProjectDir)\..\..\Something\lib</FilesDestination>
    <FilesDestination Condition=" '$(SolutionName)' == 'the top solution name' ">$(SolutionDir)\Something\lib</FilesDestination>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Error Condition=" '$(FilesDestination)' == '' " Text="Lib not delivered. To disable this message, remove the 'Target' tag from the project file" />
  <Exec Command="RD /S /Q &quot;$(FilesDestination)&quot;" />
  <Exec Command="XCOPY &quot;$(FilesSource)&quot; &quot;$(FilesDestination)&quot; /E /I /H /R /K /Y" />
  <Exec Command="RD /S /Q &quot;$(FilesSource)&quot;" />
</Target>
```

This **build event** is fired once build succeed, it cleans the `FilesDestination` folder then it copies **all files with directory structure** from `FilesSource` to `FilesDestination` and then it delete the `FilesSource` folder to keep everything "bien propre" :)

**NOTE**

For `FilesDestination`, make sure you use the **Condition** attribute or remove it to have the copy process to its end

Comment: this is only Windows compatible

Comment: Yes but a Mac compatible or native version of XCopy can be used

Comment: that adds too much complexity to your build system

Comment: This way the build system "doesn't have the full picture" and so this will, among other things, lead to unnecessary rebuilds of parts that wouldn't normally need it. Similar reason to why you shouldn't use recursive make, actually.