# VS2012 Solution Open scripting or automation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, scripting, automation

I need to copy standard component DLLs into a standard folder defined in every VS2012 project when the project is opened. We're not allowed to store DLLs in Subversion so I need to reload this folder every time a developer opens the project/solution. I'm looking for an automation solution that will pull DLLs from a centralized location and copy them into the developer's solution. I looked at Visual Studio Extensions but it seems like an awful lot of work just to copy a couple of files. Are there any other hooks in VS2012 (and hopefully VS2010) where I can code simple PowerShell scripts to copy these files?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out AntHillPro has it's own functionality for storing common DLLs and loading them into folders in your Solution before building. It's not as elegant as an MSBuild pre-build task but it fits in with the model followed by our Java builds with some slight tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Why you just do no use Nuget? Adding nuget reference and enable nuget restore on build will do exactly what you need. You can create nuget repository as shared folder.

Comment: The Nuget process is essentially a .Net-specific process. I was charged with building a .Net Build, Test and Deploy job in AntHillPro (which is really a Java ALM tool). My job has to resolve external references from an AntHillPro repository and store the generated code in the AntHillPro repository. Kind of defeats the purpose of Nuget...

Comment: did you look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119271/copy-all-files-and-folders-using-msbuild